# How often do merchants replenish their gold supply?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

How long does it take before a merchant replenishes their gold supply once I've cleaned them out? I've tried waiting for a 24 hour period and that didn't do the trick. I've also attempted to leave the zone and come back, which also didn't work. Is there a trigger for the refill? Or is it just a specific amount of time I have to wait?

Comment: In Oblivion, it was 3 days, I think?

Comment: Actually in Oblivion I'm pretty sure that they don't lose gold. That's what happened to me at least on PC. Might have been a glitch.

Comment: No, you are correct. In oblivion, the 'available gold' was more 'maximum amount of gold the merchant can pay for 1 item'. He could pay the same amount for the next item, or the 100 items after that. Skyrim *fixed* that.

Comment: Whoops. I meant their inventories, anyway.

Comment: One thing to note is that merchant gold *and inventories* respawn after a quit to desktop. This is handy if you're making rounds selling to every single merchant in a town and don't feel like fast travelling across the map for whatever reason, and is especially handy for 'farming' items such as, for instance, filled soul gems from the various merchant/trainers in Winterhold.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz is that a bug?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After two full days of waiting, the Thieves Guild fence Tonilia went from 8 gold to 1000 gold - it's possible that it varies from merchant to merchant, but two days seems standard so far.

Comment: The in-game help mentions 'every few days' (escape -> help -> barter).

Answer (score 18):

42 hours, to be exact. Sell 1000 gold worth of crap at your favorite fence, use the wait option (<kbd>T</kbd> on PC, "Back" on Xbox) and wait for 24 hours, then another 18 immediately after. No need to leave the fence's side.

Answer (score 5):

If you are on a PS3/Xbox, then you can either save and kill the merhant and reload the  save (this way they are fully restocked), or use the ways mentioned in other answer

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways you can get the merchant to "restock" on gold. Wait 42-48 hours OR save, quit to desktop and restart the game. When you log back in the merchant will be fully restocked. =)