# How long does it take Tonila to get her gold back? Or is there a better way?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How often do merchants replenish their gold supply?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35529/how-often-do-merchants-replenish-their-gold-supply)

In Skyrim, there is a fence named Tonila in the Thieves' Guild.  Unfortunately, she only has 1,000 gold at a time.  This severely limits my ability to generate money, as I have probably 20,000 gold worth of stolen goods sitting in a chest right now that I can't sell.

So the question is, how long does it take for Tonila to get her gold back after you get all her gold?  Is there a set period of time that you have to rest/wait, or do you have to go off and complete some quests, or what?

Also, if anyone has a recommendation for how to better go about generating money via selling (primarily stolen) goods to merchants, that would be more than welcome as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merchants in general in Skyrim get their gold back [in 48 hours](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Merchants). As stated in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/37512/31508) to [a similar question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35529/how-often-do-merchants-replenish-their-gold-supply), you can simply press <kbd>T</kbd> to wait the 48 hours until she restocks.

(Interestingly, UESP also mentions that saving, forcing Tonila into the recovery position, and then loading the save should force her to restock, regenerating her gold.)

There are many more fences that you will unlock as you progress through the Thieves' Guild quest line. You eventually unlock 6 stationary fences and 3 roaming fences, for [a total of 9](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Thieves_Guild_(faction)#Fences). Additionally, progressing through the Thieves' Guild quest line will increase the gold available to up to 4000 gold.

Finally, the Speech skill contains [a perk](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Speech#Fence) that turns any merchant you invest in into a fence.